# Cross XML is not work with jqm 1.4.0

Tags: android, xml, json, jquery-mobile, jsonp

i have a problem with jqm and cross xml2json 
im tried to update my jqm with ver 1.4.0 but is not working with cross xml 
here is the problem, 
 this code is working good

```
<html> 
    <head> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="xml2json.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>
    <script>

        /first.xml

        function xmlLoader(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://news.google.com.eg/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=ar_eg&hl=ar&output=rss',
                dataType: "xml",
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(res) {
                    var myXML = res.responseText;
                    // This is the part xml2Json comes in.
                    var JSONConvertedXML = $.xml2json(myXML);
                    $('#myXMLList').empty();
                    for(var i = 0; i < JSONConvertedXML.channel.item.length; i++){
                       title=JSONConvertedXML.channel.item[i].title;

                        $('#myXMLList').append('<li><a href="#"><img src="http://'+title+'" /></a></li>')
                    }
                    $('#myXMLList').listview('refresh');
                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                }
            });
        }

        $( document ).delegate("#home", "pageshow", function() {
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
            xmlLoader();
        });
    </script>
</head> 

<body> 
    <div data-role="page" id="home"> 
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Sample Cross Domain XML</h1>
        </div> 
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" id="myXMLList">

            </ul>
        </div> 
        <div data-role="footer">
            <a href="www.isgoodstuff.com" data-role="button">isGoodStuff.com</a>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i update my jqm with :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

it dosent work, any help please ?

Comment: You need to share more information than "it doesn't work". What, exactly, doesn't work?

Comment: parsing xml to json in this line code [var JSONConvertedXML = $.xml2json(myXML);]